# can't call a new activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to start a new activity from the Main activity by clicking on an image button but I get this error:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

this is my code:

```
public void WordsButton() {

   words = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.words);

   words.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WordsActivity.class);
           getApplicationContext.startActivity(intent);
       }

   });
}
```

Comment: Possible reading: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing onClick method parameter from arg0 to v to be the same like the method definition in the Interface

here is a suggestion

```
words.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WordsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Good, check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) for more understanding

Answer (score 0):

Change your `getApplicationContext.startActivity(intent);` to `startActivity(intent)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `getApplicationContext()`

Just use the standard Activity context `getContext()`

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
words.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WordsActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
       }

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
public void WordsButton() {

       words = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.words);

       words.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View arg0) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WordsActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
           }

       });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this flag to your intent

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

And Use Standard Context getContext()

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), WordsActivity.class);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      getContext.startActivity(intent);
```